# Javascript if statement with boolean

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, boolean

Im trying to create a button that make my div element show or hide, for open and close it with the same button. I dont get why it does not works, when I click on the button nothing happens, can someone help me please?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#myDIV {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the "Try it" button to set the display property of the DIV element:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>

<p><b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".</p>

<script>

var div_aperto = false;

function myFunction(div_aperto) 

   if (div_aperto) { 
       div_aperto = false;
       document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "none"; }   
   
   else { div_aperto = true;
       document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "block"; } 
      
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Run your code: `SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'if'"`.

Comment: `console.log(div_aperto)` and you are missing a opening and closing `}`

Answer (score 2):

You don't have the brackets for function statement and you don't need argument

```
function myFunction() {

   if (div_aperto) { 
       div_aperto = false;
       document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "none"; }   

   else { div_aperto = true;
       document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "block"; } 
}
```

Comment: still will not work....

Comment: Did you get rid of the argument of the function?

Comment: I am not the OP and you edited it after I said that...

Comment: Solved, thank you guys! <3

Answer (score 2):

Beyond the missing `{}`, note your function accepts an argument, but your sending it nothing (`myfunction()`). This will cause the `div_aperto` to always be undefined when the function starts. If you want to reference the global drop the argument.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#myDIV {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the "Try it" button to set the display property of the DIV element:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>

<p><b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".</p>

<script>

var div_aperto = false;

function myFunction()  {
   if (div_aperto) { 
       div_aperto = false;
       document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "none"; }   
   
   else { div_aperto = true;
       document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "block"; } 
}  
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you missed the opening and closing brackets of the function definition.

I also linked a working fiddle, try it out. :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <style>
      #myDIV {
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: lightblue;
        display: none;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <p>Click the "Try it" button to set the display property of the DIV element:</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <div id="myDIV">
      This is my DIV element.
    </div>

    <p><b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".</p>

    <script>
      var div_aperto = false;

      function myFunction(div_aperto) {

        if (div_aperto) {
          div_aperto = false;
          document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "none";
        } else {
          div_aperto = true;
          document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "block";
        }

      }

    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xmzh92z9/1/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're shadowing `div_aperto` in the declaration of your function. Its value is thus always `undefined` in the function.

Change

```
function myFunction(div_aperto)
```

to

```
function myFunction() {
```

You also need to add the braces around the function body.

Demonstration:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#myDIV {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the "Try it" button to set the display property of the DIV element:</p>
<script>

var div_aperto = false;

function myFunction() {

   if (div_aperto) { 
       div_aperto = false;
       document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "none"; }   
   
   else { div_aperto = true;
       document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "block"; } 
      }
</script>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>

<p><b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".</p>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: still will not work, more issues than just that.

Comment: @epascarello I think the missing braces is just a too short paste

Answer (score 0):

You need to put all the sentences of the `myFunction` between `{}`, also if you declare your `div_aperto` variable as global, you don't have to pass it as argument to the function:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#myDIV {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the "Try it" button to set the display property of the DIV element:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>

<p><b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".</p>

<script>

var div_aperto = false;

function myFunction() {
   if (div_aperto) { 
       div_aperto = false;
       document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "none"; 
   } else { 
      div_aperto = true;
      document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "block"; 
   }    
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works, so I just needed to add { } to the function! I wasted so much time!! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Simple.
Remove your script code and add bellow script

```
<script>

var div_aperto = false;

function myFunction() 
{
   if (div_aperto) { 
       div_aperto = false;
       document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "none"; }   

   else { div_aperto = true;
       document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "block"; } 
      }
</script>
```

Comment: It works, so I just needed to add { } to the function! I wasted so much time!! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome....cheers